# Accurately calculating gravity for large systems

Tags: java, performance, physics

I'm in the middle of a program to simulate gravity between particles for > 50000 particles. It works so far, but the way I calculate gravity seems to be a tad askew. Generally, it works. It fails when particles get too close (distance between them approaching 0, gravitational force approaching infinity). I believe this is because of how the implementation chunks up time. It can only calculate the gravity between frames, and I can shorten the time between frames but the problem still exists.

Here's the implementation:

```
//The time between frames
static final double planc = 0.002;

//Calculates distance^2 between two particles
public double d2(Particle p) {

    return (x - p.x) * (x - p.x) + (y - p.y) * (y - p.y);

}

//Gets Vector from on particle pointing to the next
public Vector getVec(Particle p) {

    return new Vector(p.x - x, p.y - y);

}

//The function that actually (independently) moves the particles according 
//to the forces acting on them
public void move() {

    //v is a Vector that represents the force (not acceleration) 
    //acting on the particle
    x += v.dx * planc / m;
    y += v.dy * planc / m;

}

//Actually calculates gravity
public boolean grav(Particle p) {

    double d2 = d2(p);

    //Happens once because of how the function is used (unimportant)
    if (d2 == 0)
        return false;

    //-1000 is the G value
    double f = -1000 * m * p.m / d2;

    //Creates acceleration-vectors
    Vector v = getVec(p);
    v.normTo(f * planc, Math.sqrt(d2));//sets v's magnitude to f * planc. 2nd parameter saves a calculation
    //Basically formats a vector which represents gravitational acceleration

    //"adds" force-vector to both particles
    this.v.sub(v);
    p.v.add(v);

    return false;

}
```

This is fast but sacrifices accuracy. Is there a better way to calculate gravity for large n-body systems (that doesn't screw over performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Gravity for small distances

I've seen two simple ways that are used to fix this problem:

1. Add a small amount to each distance:

   ```
   double d2 = d2(p);

   d2 += EPSILON_DIST;
   ```
2. Use a minimum distance:

   ```
   double d2 = d2(p);

   if (d2 < MIN_DIST)
       d2 = MIN_DIST;
   ```

Either way will prevent small distances from causing huge accelerations.  Since `d2` is in units of distance squared, your `EPSILON_DIST` and `MIN_DIST` should also be squared distances.

#### More efficient gravity computation

Your gravity calculation could be improved a little.  I [answered another almost identical question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88568/58193), so you can take a look at the solution I came up with there.  The main point is that you can reduce the number of divisions to only one in `grav()` and zero in `move()`.  Although it doesn't exactly match your `Particle` class, I think you can extrapolate from it.  Here is the code, pasted from that other question:

```
public void interact(Body other) {
    double dx = other.getX() - x;
    double dy = other.getY() - y;
    double r  = calculateDistance(dx, dy);
    double inv_r3 = 1.0 / (r * r * r);

    /* Precalculate force component (1/r^2) times direction (dx/r) = dx / r^3 */
    dx *= inv_r3;
    dy *= inv_r3;

    /* calculate accelerations for both bodies */
    vx += other.getMass() * dx;
    vy += other.getMass() * dy;
    other.addToVx(mass * -dx);
    other.addToVy(mass * -dy);
}

public void update() {
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
}
```